# Persisting container data php

Tags: php, laravel, oop, dependency-injection, ioc-container

I am building a container for a project where I need to persist some data. I have taken some ideas from Laravel and reworked it into a small code example. I am wondering why my second example does not work in this case.

**Application class example:**

```
class Application extends Container
{
    /**
     * Bind these into the container.
     */
    public function bootstrap()
    {
        static::setInstance($this);

        $this->bind('debugStack', new DebugStack());
        $this->bind('database', new Database());
    }
}
```

**Container class example:**

```
class Container
{
    protected static $instance;

    protected $registry = [];

    public function bind($key, $value)
    {
        $this->registry[$key] = $value;
    }

    public function get($key)
    {
        if (!array_key_exists($key, $this->registry)) {
            throw new \Exception("No {$key} is bound in the container");
        }

        return $this->registry[$key];
    }

    /**
     * Set the globally available instance of the container.
     *
     * @return static
     */
    public static function getInstance()
    {
        if (is_null(static::$instance)) {
            static::$instance = new static;
        }

        return static::$instance;
    }

    // Allow access to the entire app context.
    public static function setInstance($container = null)
    {
        return static::$instance = $container;
    }
}
```

**Reworked example(2nd):**

```
class Application extends Container
{
    /**
     * Bind these into the container.
     */
    public function bootstrap()
    {
        static::getInstance();

        $this->bind('debugStack', new DebugStack());
        $this->bind('database', new Database());
    }
}
```

The `getInstance` already checks if an instance `is_null` and provides a new instance if no instance is found. My bind functions run fine but this way my data is not persisted.

I am confused on why my data is persisted in the first example but not in the second. Hopefully somebody can explain me why this happens.

If you need more info let me know.

Comment: Is the removal of `$this` in this line `static::setInstance();` intentional?

Comment: Shouldn't `static::$instance = new static;` be `static::$instance = new Container;` ?

Comment: @H2ONOCK same thing, that does not matter.

Comment: Apologies, what I should have written is `static::$instance = new Application;`